# How do I allow project user setting to be of type List<string>?

Tags: c#, app-config, settings

My app currently uses the user settings system (via project properties) to store user specific data.  I use these settings instead of writing to/from App.Config because I need the data to persist when ClickOnce updates their build.

Right now I am needing the user to be able to specify a list of strings to be stored in user settings.  I already deal with settings in a C# PropertyGrid, and I have verified that if I set `MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = new List<string>()`, it gives me a proper editor to edit a list of strings.

Unfortunately, when I go to Project Preferences -> Settings and click Browse for the type, I cannot select List or find any good types to use for a string list.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to store a list of strings in the user settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your own settings manually when the designer won't let you choose the types. This can happen with some built-in types and with a lot of your own custom types. Here's a link to a similar question on SO:

[Why am I unable to select a custom Type for a setting from the same project/assembly as the settings file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042180/why-am-i-unable-to-select-a-custom-type-for-a-setting-from-the-same-project-assem)

and here's a link to an answer (it's in VB.NET but the principles apply):

http://blog.coretech.dk/jgs/add-custom-data-type-structure-to-mysettings-in-vbnet-wpf/

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, if only because it gives a good link on how to make types available in the user settings GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I can see `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` in the list of types. Why don't you just use this?

You can use the following conversions between `StringCollection` and `List<string>`:

```
var stringList = stringCollection.Cast<string>().ToList();

var stringCollection = new StringCollection();
stringCollection.AddRange(stringList.ToArray());
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that.  Unfortunately after trying this out, property grids don't really like them, as when I click to add a new one I get `Constructor on type 'System.String' not found'. :-/

Comment: Can't you use a `List<string>` for the property grid and convert that to a `StringCollection` before saving it?

Comment: The property grid is being hooked straight up to the the `Properties.Settings.Default` object.  I guess I could create a DTO or intermediary class just for the property grid usage

Comment: Nevermind, contrary to what I thought before, `List<string>` doesn't actually work either.  I get the same error as with `StringCollection`

Comment: @KallDrexx: I think you should accept an answer here (preferably mine `*g*`) and open a new question, because your original question has been solved.

Comment: @KallDrexx: BTW: The reason why it isn't working is that string is immutable and doesn't have a default constructor without parameters. How to solve that problem I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to do it by the designer, but you can manual edit the settings file.

The thing is, that VS allows to serialize int[] type by default in the settings file - it just doesn't allow you to select it by default. So, create a setting with desired name (e.g. SomeTestSetting) and make it of any type (e.g. string by default). Save the changes.

Now go to your project folder and open the "Properties\Settings.settings" file with text editor (Notepad, for example) Or you can open it in VS by right-clicking in Solution Explorer on " -> Properties -> Settings.settings", select "Open With..." and then choose either "XML Editor" or "Source Code (Text) Editor". In the opened xml settings find your setting (it will look like this):

```
<Setting Name="SomeTestSetting" Type="System.String" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

Change the "Type" param from System.String to List. Now this section will look like this:

```
<Setting Name="SomeTestSetting" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```