# Add a collection of a custom class to Settings.Settings

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, .net-4.0, settings

I've been having a helluva time trying to add a custom collection of a custom class to the application settings of my winforms project I feel like Ive tried it about six different ways, including [this way](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file), [this way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321248/how-do-i-save-serialize-a-custom-class-to-the-settings-file), and [this way](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/aa13ecaf-07a5-4833-bd0c-2cb73e5235dc) but nothing seems to work...

Currently the code complies, and runs fine - no exceptions anywhere.  Code his the Save function but no entries are created in the settings xml file (I have a few other settings and it works for all of them but this one FYI).  When it loads, `Properties.Settings.Default.LastSearches` is always null... Any thoughts?

Heres my current code:

**The Classes:**

```
[Serializable]
public class LastSearch : ISerializable
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Hour { get; set; }
    public string Log { get; set; }
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedFilters { get; set; }
    public List<string> SearchTerms { get; set; }
    public List<string> HighlightedTerms { get; set; }
    public List<string> ExcludedTerms { get; set; }

    public LastSearch(DateTime date, string hour, string log, string command, List<string> selectedFilters,
        List<string> searchTerms, List<string> highlightedTerms, List<string> excludedTerms)
    {
        Date = date.ToUniversalTime();
        Hour = hour;
        Log = log;
        Command = command;
        SelectedFilters = selectedFilters;
        SearchTerms = searchTerms;
        HighlightedTerms = highlightedTerms;
        ExcludedTerms = excludedTerms;
    }

    protected LastSearch(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Date = info.GetDateTime("Date");
        Hour = info.GetString("Hour");
        Log = info.GetString("Log");
        Command = info.GetString("Command");
        SelectedFilters = (List<string>)info.GetValue("SelectedFilters", typeof(List<string>));
        SearchTerms = (List<string>)info.GetValue("SearchTerms", typeof(List<string>));
        HighlightedTerms = (List<string>)info.GetValue("HighlightedTerms", typeof(List<string>));
        ExcludedTerms = (List<string>)info.GetValue("ExcludedTerms", typeof(List<string>));
    }
    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Date", Date);
        info.AddValue("Hour", Hour);
        info.AddValue("Log", Log);
        info.AddValue("Command", Command);
        info.AddValue("SelectedFilters", SelectedFilters);
        info.AddValue("SearchTerms", SearchTerms);
        info.AddValue("HighlightedTerms", HighlightedTerms);
        info.AddValue("ExcludedTerms", ExcludedTerms);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class LastSearchCollection : ISerializable
{
    public List<LastSearch> Searches { get; set; }

    public LastSearchCollection()
    {
        Searches = new List<LastSearch>();
    }

    public LastSearchCollection(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        Searches = (List<LastSearch>)info.GetValue("LastSearches", typeof(List<LastSearch>));
    }
    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Searches", Searches);
    }
}
```

**Writing to Settings:**

```
if (RecentQueriesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count > 0)
{
    // Last Search Settings
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.LastSearches == null)
        Properties.Settings.Default.LastSearches = new LastSearchCollection();

    Properties.Settings.Default.LastSearches.Searches.Clear();
    foreach (LastSearchMenuItem item in RecentQueriesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.LastSearches.Searches.Add(item.SearchData);
    }
}

// Save all settings
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**Loading from setttings**

```
// Last Searches
if (Properties.Settings.Default.LastSearches != null)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (LastSearch search in Properties.Settings.Default.LastSearches.Searches)
    {
        LastSearchMenuItem searchMenuItem = new LastSearchMenuItem(search);
        RecentQueriesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(searchMenuItem);
        RecentQueriesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[i].Click += new EventHandler(RecentSearch_Click);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: can I ask why you are trying to store this in the User settings? Why not just serialize your class to disk?

Comment: @Jethro That's exactly what the built in user setting does really.  I already have all my other settings in there and it made sense to try and keep it all together.

Comment: Have you seen this article on how to persist custom class. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WinAppUserSettings.aspx

Comment: @Jethro Thanks! However I still do want to try and make this work with the built in settings

Comment: @Jethro Well I ended up using your link so if you put that as an answer Ill accept it

Answer (score 8):

After more than 8 years i had the same need that you had. I solved it using XML Serialization to store the custom collection in the user settings.

Here is an example adopted to your code.

**First of all** you need to set the type of your setting to the type of your collection class (e.g. "MyProject.LastSearchCollection"). See [Why am I unable to select a custom Type for a setting from the same project/assembly as the settings file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11890426/6764710) on how to do this.
If Visual Studio says it can't find your custom class, make sure the class is public and has a public, parameterless constructor.

**The custom class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MyProject
{
    [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
    public class LastSearch
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Hour { get; set; }
        public string Log { get; set; }
        public string Command { get; set; }
        public List<string> SelectedFilters { get; set; }
        public List<string> SearchTerms { get; set; }
        public List<string> HighlightedTerms { get; set; }
        public List<string> ExcludedTerms { get; set; }

        public LastSearch(DateTime date, string hour, string log, string command, List<string> selectedFilters,
            List<string> searchTerms, List<string> highlightedTerms, List<string> excludedTerms)
        {
            Date = date.ToUniversalTime();
            Hour = hour;
            Log = log;
            Command = command;
            SelectedFilters = selectedFilters;
            SearchTerms = searchTerms;
            HighlightedTerms = highlightedTerms;
            ExcludedTerms = excludedTerms;
        }

        protected LastSearch(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            Date = info.GetDateTime("Date");
            Hour = info.GetString("Hour");
            Log = info.GetString("Log");
            Command = info.GetString("Command");
            SelectedFilters = (List<string>)info.GetValue("SelectedFilters", typeof(List<string>));
            SearchTerms = (List<string>)info.GetValue("SearchTerms", typeof(List<string>));
            HighlightedTerms = (List<string>)info.GetValue("HighlightedTerms", typeof(List<string>));
            ExcludedTerms = (List<string>)info.GetValue("ExcludedTerms", typeof(List<string>));
        }
    }

    [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
    public class LastSearchCollection
    {
        public List<LastSearch> Searches { get; set; }

        public LastSearchCollection()
        {
            Searches = new List<LastSearch>();
        }

        public LastSearchCollection(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            Searches = (List<LastSearch>)info.GetValue("LastSearches", typeof(List<LastSearch>));
        }
    }
}
```

The only differences are, that i added the `[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]` attributes and removed your serialization functions.
You may have to add the reference `System.Configuration` to your project.

**Save the settings just like:**

```
LastSearchCollection searches =  new LastSearchCollection();

List<string> selectedFilters = new List<string>();
selectedFilters.Add("Filter1");
selectedFilters.Add("Filter2");
selectedFilters.Add("FilterN");

searches.Searches.Add(new LastSearch(DateTime.Now, "7", "Log1", "CommandA", selectedFilters, new List<string>(), new List<string>(), new List<string>()));
searches.Searches.Add(new LastSearch(DateTime.Now, "9", "Log2", "CommandB", new List<string>(), new List<string>(), new List<string>(), new List<string>()));
Properties.Settings.Default.LastSearches = searches;

// Save all settings
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Afterwards the user.config written to disc will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    ...
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
    ...
        <MyProject.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="LastSearches" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value>
                    <LastSearchCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <Searches>
                            <LastSearch>
                                <Date>2020-03-01T07:49:44.5512864Z</Date>
                                <Hour>7</Hour>
                                <Log>Log1</Log>
                                <Command>CommandA</Command>
                                <SelectedFilters>
                                    <string>Filter1</string>
                                    <string>Filter2</string>
                                    <string>FilterN</string>
                                </SelectedFilters>
                                <SearchTerms />
                                <HighlightedTerms />
                                <ExcludedTerms />
                            </LastSearch>
                            <LastSearch>
                                <Date>2020-03-01T07:49:44.5562864Z</Date>
                                <Hour>9</Hour>
                                <Log>Log2</Log>
                                <Command>CommandB</Command>
                                <SelectedFilters />
                                <SearchTerms />
                                <HighlightedTerms />
                                <ExcludedTerms />
                            </LastSearch>
                        </Searches>
                    </LastSearchCollection>
                </value>
            </setting>
        </MyProject.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```