# Serializing list of objects to .settings

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, settings.settings

I was trying to serialize a list of objects to my user.settings file. I've tried a lot of things, and the only thing I got to work was the solution here. [Add a collection of a custom class to Settings.Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000625/add-a-collection-of-a-custom-class-to-settings-settings?lq=1) I tried many different things, but this one was the only one that consistently worked.

**Edit**: What I am trying to serialize is either a List of objects (of a serializable class), or just a list of Tuples

The solution looks like this:

```
public class Favorites: ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [SettingsSerializeAs(System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
    [DefaultSettingValue("")]
    public System.Collections.ArrayList FavoritesList
    {
        get
        {
            return ((System.Collections.ArrayList)this["FavoritesList"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["FavoritesList"] = (System.Collections.ArrayList)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Technically, it works. However, I wanted to get it to work as XML serialization, not as binary. Switching over to SettingsSerializeAs.Xml, it doesn't serialize the settings, all I get are an empty tag for these settings. Do I have to do it differently when I serialize settings as XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work looking like this, with the Settings storing an object of the type "Favorites":

```
public sealed class Favorites : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    public Favorites()
    {
        this.FavoritesList = new List<Favorite>();
    }

    [UserScopedSetting]
    public List<Favorite> FavoritesList
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<Favorite>)this["FavoritesList"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["FavoritesList"] = value;
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Favorit
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XmlSerializer and in code serialize your collection.

Then you can save serialized data string into settings.

Comment: I assume, serialize EVERYTHING I need of (in this case) favorites, the entire list of objects, and just put that into one settings string, but I'd have liked to avoid a solution that somewhat works "outside" the Settings mechanism...

Answer (score 1):

Try this please,

```
public class Favorites: ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    private String[] favoritesList;

    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FavoritesList")]
    [DefaultSettingValue("")]
    public String[] FavoritesList
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.favoritesList);
        }
        set
        {
            this.favoritesList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I've used array of string data type. But ideally it can be an array of your custom object

Comment: if, as of your example, I use "Tuple<int, int>[]" (or even string[]), and then use it this way, create Favorites object, create list if null, add data, save favorites object, then no settings file is created.

Comment: Is it possible for you share the entire class?