# Using own enum in settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to use my own enum in a project setting (from Visual studio, menu project,  properties, tab settings).

I can select a lot of default types there, but even types from other projects in my solution, but not the project itsself.

Is it possible to use an enumeration type from the project itsself as type for a setting?

Comment: Please be aware that tags are not keywords.  That is, combining the tags `visual` and `studio` does not mean that you are talking about Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it takes a bit of twiddling. See [this](http://blog.coretech.dk/jgs/add-custom-data-type-structure-to-mysettings-in-vbnet-wpf/) article for pointers on how to accomplish it.

Comment: Probably the best way, but indeed too much work (gives many other questions).

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I would know.

But you could do something like:

```
string setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("yourSetting");
YourEnum yourEnumVariable = (YourEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(YourEnum), setting);
```

(Written just here without IDE sytax checking, please forgive any syntax mistakes.)

Comment: Currently I'm using int's but strings might be better (using switches takes a lot of code).

Comment: Just checked ... but I'm missing type safety in that case, don't think int's or strings would really matter much.

Answer (score 0):

Easily.

Although the picklist shows you Types from all kinds of assemblies except your own, if you type the exact `NamespaceQualified.NameOfYourEnum` into the textbox at the bottom, it will work, and the GUI will show you a dropdown of Enum values.

Tested in VS2013.

If you make a mistake it is caught during build, and you can edit the settings.settings file to fix.