# Types Not Updated In Properties Settings Page Of .NET C# Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, enums

I have a project which adds a reference to a class library project. Within this class library is a file of enums. What I wanted to do is add a couple of enums to this file and then from my main project, go to Properties->Settings and add a user setting which has a type of this enum. On the Type combo box I select Browse and from there the class library project. However, only the previous enums show up in this list. They are all declared as public. I have rebuilt everything and deleted the reference and re-added it but it makes no difference.

Why are the new enums not showing up in the list?

**Update:
As the comment below, I have now fixed this. The solution was to close Visual Studio and reopen it. A bug in Visual Studio by the looks of things.**

Comment: Have you tried to clear solution?

Comment: Yes. They still don't show up.

Comment: I hope that answer for this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184209/custom-enum-as-application-setting-type-in-c

Comment: Not that sure what a 'file of enums' might look like.  But surely you have to rebuild that class library first, required to get added enum values to show up in the settings page.

Comment: Yes of course I rebuilt the class library first. It makes no difference.

Comment: I have now fixed this and it was the one thing I didn't think to try. I closed Visual Studio and reopened it and now they appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: As stated, I have now fixed this. The solution was to close Visual Studio and reopen it. A bug in Visual Studio by the looks of things.